# full adder gate

Tags: logic

I don't know if this question is considered to be related to stackoverflow (I'm sorry if it's not but I have searched and did not find an answer anywhere).

I have coded a full adder

Output:

```
Truth Table : 

a1  a2   b1   b2   S1   S2   C
______________________________
0   0    0    0    0    0    0
0   0    0    1    0    1    0
0   0    1    0    1    0    0
0   0    1    1    1    1    0
0   1    0    0    0    1    0
0   1    0    1    0    0    1
0   1    1    0    1    1    0
0   1    1    1    1    0    1
1   0    0    0    1    0    0
1   0    0    1    1    1    0
1   0    1    0    0    1    0
1   0    1    1    0    0    1
1   1    0    0    1    1    0
1   1    0    1    1    0    1
1   1    1    0    0    0    1
1   1    1    1    0    1    1
```

If somebody has ever calculated this, can they tell me if my output is correct

Comment: I have googled for "full adder truth table" and was *inundated* with results.

Comment: Superficially it looks correct.  It's a bit confusing, of course, since the table is "upside down" from the standpoint of normal numbering, but it's probably the best way to present a truth table (which I've only ever done maybe a half-dozen times, despite having designed integrated circuits for NASA).

Comment: can i test it manually in some way please?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better site for this question.

Comment: Sure you can test it.  Wire together two full adders with switches and lights and go to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a1  a2   b1   b2   S1   S2   C   a  b  s  c
______________________________
0   0    0    0    0    0    0   0  0  0  0 nothing plus nothing is nothing
0   0    0    1    0    1    0   0  2  2  0 nothing plus two is two
0   0    1    0    1    0    0   0  1  1  0 nothing plus one is one
0   0    1    1    1    1    0   0  3  3  0 nothing plus three is three
0   1    0    0    0    1    0   2  0  2  0 two plus nothing is two
0   1    0    1    0    0    1   2  2  0  1 two plus two is four (four not in 0-3)
0   1    1    0    1    1    0   2  1  3  0 two plus 1 is three
0   1    1    1    1    0    1   2  3  1  1 two plus three is five (one and four)  
1   0    0    0    1    0    0   1  0  1  0 one plus nothing is one
1   0    0    1    1    1    0   1  2  3  0 one plus two is three
1   0    1    0    0    1    0   1  1  2  0 one plus one is two
1   0    1    1    0    0    1   1  3  0  1 one plus three is four
1   1    0    0    1    1    0   3  0  3  0 three plus nothing is three
1   1    0    1    1    0    1   3  2  1  1 three plus two is five (one and four)
1   1    1    0    0    0    1   3  1  0  1 three plus one is four
1   1    1    1    0    1    1   3  3  2  1 three plus three is 6 (two and four)
```

Looks right. Ordering your 16 rows a little differently would make them flow in a more logical order.

Comment: Right now the rows are driven in bit order (a1, a2, b1, b2) and result in the combined value for A being presented as 0,2,1,3 rather than 0,1,2,3. It doesn't affect the correctness of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's an adder!  Just check if it's adding. Let's take this row:

```
 a2 a1     b2 b1     C S2 S2 
  1  0      1  1     1  0  1
```

Here I have reordered the columns in an easier to read manner: higher order bits first.

The `a` input is 10 = 2 (base 10).  The `b` input is 11 = 3 (base 10). The output is 101, which 
is 5 (base 10).  So this one is right:  2 + 3 == 5.

I'll let you check the other rows.

Comment: I don't get how you got the 6 part, it was 101

Comment: Sorry I missed that you had the columns ordered backward.  Fixed now.

Comment: thanks, a lot but why does it come good it you do higher order bits first and not otherwise?

Comment: Because that's how numbers are written.  In 23 the highest order digit is 2 (not 3).